# C# Converting .xlsx to .xls

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I used ClosedXML.dll to create Excel file, however ClosedXML saves the excel file as .xlsx and my client's PC only runs Office 2003 so they cannot open the .xlsx file, how can I convert that .xlsx to .xls?

Any recommendations will be appreciated. Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask your client to install the [Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3), if possible, which will let them open Office 2007 format documents in Office 2003.

Answer (score 2):

Download the MS Office Compatibility Pack from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads.

Comment: Why would you post this when it's quite clearly already been posted?

Comment: I was editing my post as the other guy had added his answer, It wasn't present on my screen as I posted it, but thanks for making me aware.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Excel c#](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview) to [Convert XLSX to XLS](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/support/articles/convert-xls-xlsx-ods-csv-html-net)

With a code like this:

```
// Create new XLSX file.
var xlsxFile = new ExcelFile();

// Load data from XLSX file.
xlsxFile.LoadXlsx(fileName + ".xls", XlsxOptions.PreserveMakeCopy);

// Save XLSX file to XLS file.
xlsxFile.SaveXls(fileName + ".xls");
```

Comment: If you check the Website of the software there is a Free version.

Comment: Indeed. It limits you to 150 lines per sheet, maximum 5 sheets per workbook, but it exists. All in all, I keep my -1, because I still feel this should be stated in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try NET Office (http://netoffice.codeplex.com/), It converts xls to xlsx so you can use closedXML with the files

Answer (score 0):

Try use [ExcelDataReader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) and [ExcelPlusPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). They are open source and good

Answer (score 0):

I posted a question just a few days ago regarding this.

**Note** This is a `vba` solution.

This loops through a folder opening each workbook in turn and saving them in .xls format. Simply change the path marked C:xxx to the location of your .xlsx files. It avoids having to ask end users to do things to open your product and in my experience if you have a lot of users you will some incapable or unwilling to install a compatibility pack.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Convert_to972003()
    Dim orgwb As Workbook
    Dim mypath As String, strfilename As String
    Dim nname As String

    '--> Error Handling
    On Error GoTo WhatHappened

    '--> Disable Alerts
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    '--> Specify location of workbooks
    mypath = "C:\xxx"
    strfilename = Dir(mypath & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)

    '--> Check the specified folder contains files
    If Len(strfilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    '--> Start Loop, end when last file reached
    Do Until strfilename = ""

    '--> Open a workbook
        Set orgwb = Application.Workbooks.Open _
        (mypath & "\" & strfilename)

        '--> Create new Filename, Save in new File Format and Close
        nname = Replace(strfilename, ".xlsx", ".xls")
        orgwb.SaveAs mypath & "\" & nname, FileFormat:=xlExcel8
        orgwb.Close
        strfilename = Dir()
    Loop

    '--> Enable Alerts
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

Exit Sub

WhatHappened: MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .XlFileFormat.xlExcel7 to format excel 95 files.

Answer (score -1):

From the [FAQ of ClosedXML.dll](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Does%20it%20support%20Excel%202003%20and%20prior%20formats%20%28.xls%29?&referringTitle=Documentation):

> Does it support Excel 2003 and prior formats (.xls)? Nope. ClosedXML
>   only supports Excel 2007/2010 format (.xlsx).
>
> Last edited May 16 2011 at 7:45 PM by MDeLeon, version 1
>
> sec_goat Jul 19 at 5:54 PM  I do not know if this is the right place,
>   but this is the workaround I used for xls files. I open them in
>   Interop.Excel and save them as the newer file type. This is not the
>   most elegant but it at least gives people an idea of what they can do.

```
public void Convert(String filesFolder)
{
  files = Directory.GetFiles(filesFolder);

  var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
  var wb = app.Workbooks.Open(file);
  wb.SaveAs(Filename: file + "x", FileFormat: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
  wb.Close();
  app.Quit();
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: That's how to convert from .XLS to .XLSX. The questioner asks the opposite. Using Interop might be appropriate, though. However, I assume (perhaps wrongly) that they are using ClosedXML because they can't use interop.

Comment: whoops, sorry, should I delete this then?